# How to persist alias for a plesk ssh terminal session

Tags: command-line, ssh

I have my website hosted on a Plesk environment and have the option to login via ssh to the server. I have a Laravel installation there an want to create the alias `art` to execute `/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php artisan`.

I can do

```
alias art="/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php artisan"
```

but the next time I log in the alias is gone.
Is there any way to make this persist for the user?

Comment: You have to define the alias on the system you ssh to... like in [Replace $ in terminal prompt with user@host when using SSH](//askubuntu.com/a/814270) but replace the stuff about PS1 with your alias... Also vaguely related: [Why doesn't my alias work over ssh?](//askubuntu.com/q/810098)

Comment: @Zanna normaly you would add it to the ~/.bashrc file. But how / where do you add it on a Plesk based system?

Comment: er... +1 to your question because I have no idea how to answer that!